# Save values of multiple text boxes using jquery and mysql

Tags: php, jquery

How to insert dynamically generated field values to backend using mysql.

Im trying to add rows with text box and drop down using jquery and auto saving 
the field values at regular intervals.

So i need to fetch the ids of the textboxes and drop down, but currently i get the id of only the first text box and drop down.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function() {
        AddControl();
    });

    $("#btnGet").bind("click", function() {
        var values = "";
        $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function() {
            values += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });
        alert(values);
    });

    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
        var i = 1;
        var Ids = [];
        $('[id*=ddl]').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("id", "ddl" + i);
            Ids.push(i);
            i++;
        });
        $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val(parseInt($('[id*=hfDDLId]').val()) - 1);
            var resultIds = Ids.join(',');
            $('[id*=hfDropDownIds]').val(resultIds);
        });
    });

    function AddControl() {
        var Id = parseInt($('[id*=hfDDLId]').val()) + 1;
        var ddlId = "ddl" + (Id);
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(getDropDownList(ddlId, ddlId));
        div.append(GetDynamicTextBox(''));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
        $('[id*=hfDDLId]').val(Id);

        var previousDropDownId = $('[id*=hfDropDownIds]').val();
        if (previousDropDownId != '') {
            $('[id*=hfDropDownIds]').val(previousDropDownId + ',' + Id);
        } else {
            $('[id*=hfDropDownIds]').val(Id);
        }
        return false;
    }

    function getDropDownList(name, id) {
        var combo = $("<select></select>").attr("id", id).attr("name", name).attr("runat", "server").attr("class", "class").attr("required", "required");
        combo.append("<option value=" + "" + ">" + "Select Category" + "</option>");
        combo.append("<option value=" + "1" + ">" + "1" + "</option>");
        combo.append("<option value=" + "2" + ">" + "2" + "</option>");
        combo.append("<option value=" + "3" + ">" + "3" + "</option>");
        return combo;
    }

    function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox"  id="ingr_name" type="text" value = "' + value + '" required/>&nbsp' + '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value="' + value + '" required/>&nbsp' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="TextBoxContainer">
            <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
        </div>
        <br/>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfSelectedValue" runat="server" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfDropDownIds" value="" runat="server" />
        <input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Get Values" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hfDDLId" value="0" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Code for inserting in the backend

Assunimg i have given the id for the text box as 'ingr_name' im posting the same as :

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","pass","DB");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['txt_area']) && $_POST['txt_area'] != '') {    

$ingr_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['ingr_name']);  
$qry = "Select count(*) as cnt from table";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$qry);    
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);   
if ($row['cnt'] == 0) {
   $qry_ins = 'my insert query';
}
?>
```

Comment: change all your ids to classes problem solved

Comment: First thing dynamic generated text box you haven't added id of that box. you have added same name in all box you are checking with name. instead of apply conman class name and then start each loop based on class name.

Comment: [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only returns the value of a single element. So you're selectors are getting everything but you only get the value from the first element in the list. Instead, make some arrays, for-loop through the selected elements and push each value onto the corresponding array. Also, though jquery might be able to select the elements using your selectors, it's better to make sure every element on the page has a unique id.

Comment: Add same name to dynamically generated text boxes you can do this like `text_name[]` for all text boxes. Now in jquery you can get all the form values using `serialize()` function. Now in your backend using for loop on textbox values insert them in mysql.

Comment: Assuming i have added the id to textbox as 'ingr_name' and updated the code for inserting the value of the text box, could you please suggest on how to proceed @Prudhvi259

Answer (score 0):

@SachinSachin if you want to insert only one text box value try the below code

```
function insert_data(){
            var url = "insert.php";
            $.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#formid').serialize(),

                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);

                    }
                });
        }
```

call this function on submit button and in insert.php you get the values using post method as usual and insert them in mysql. if it is success print `echo "inserted";` else print `echo "failed"`; you will get this status in alert message in above `insert_data()` function. Here i assumed you are using php as backend if not use your language with same process.

Comment: i want to insert all the fields value to backend... text box, drop down on submit and remove from backend if i click on remove

Comment: to insert all text box and drop down fields first use same name for all text boxes and another same name for all drop down list and form submission is as as above. Now in backed you will get all text box values as array with  the name you used and drop down list values also same.  And for remove, before submit you no need backend.

Comment: can u please explain in code as im new to ajax and frontend techs and this insert of different text box should happen to different tables..tis is whr im stuck